# Is 'handshaking' a legitimate word?

Tags: word-choice, is-it-a-word

In microprocessors, handshake signals are issued by a microprocessor in acknowledgement of a request by another device.

This process has been repeatedly referred to as 'handshaking' in my lectures.

Is it a commonly used term in general English?

Comment: As always in such cases, I have to ask for clarification: what *is* an illegitimate word? Obviously you see the word is being used, you understand that it has a clear meaning, that meaning is known to you, and you can explain it to others. So, what is your question exactly? Please clarify. "Legitimate word" is not a term. We can only tell if a word is legitimate if you define "legitimate" first.

Answer (score 6):

I was about to brand this question 'General Reference', but the verb 'handshake' hasn't yet been recognised by say AHD and Collins.

At http://www.dicts.info/define.php?word=handshaking is found:

> **handshake**
>
> noun
>
> grasping and shaking a person's hand (as to acknowledge an
>   introduction or to agree on a contract) handshake  shake  handshaking 
>   handclasp
>   WordNet Lexical Database v3.0, © 2006 Princeton University
>
> **handshaking** in English Wiktionary
>
> (verb) (present participle of/handshake#Verb/handshake) (noun)
>
> A greeting by clasping hands.
>
> (noun) (computers)
>
> A step in a protocol in which information is
>   exchanged between computing processor devices; often as part of the
>   initiation process for communications.
>
> Wiktionary, GNU Free Documentation Licence

Though some major dictionaries haven't yet caught up with the usage you mention, I wouldn't worry at all about the word's being used in computing. The usual 'rules' for morphology are being observed, and 'handshaking' is non-confusing, very handy to use, and cleverly appropriated from its original sense.

Answer (score 3):

The entry for the noun *handshake* in the OED (Third Edition, June 2013) has as its third definition:

> Computing. An exchange of standardized signals between communicating
>   devices in a network or bus, used to regulate the transfer of data
>   between them, typically to control the start or end of a transmission;
>   a signal used for this purpose.

The entry for the verb gives only the traditional sense, but there’s no reason why the verbal use shouldn’t be extended to computing if it’s helpful to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Is the verb, *to handshake*, commonly used in *every day* English? No, not really.

When heartily agreeing with someone, I wouldn't say:

> I'd like **to handshake** (with?) you, if I may.

Instead I would and have said many a time,

> I'd like **to shake your hand**, if I may.

When making a deal, or coming to a conclusion to a lengthy debate it is quite common to say:

> Let's **shake hands** on it.

Does this mean no one will understand if you were to use *handshake* as a verb starting from today? I don't think so, the meaning is pretty straightforward, no room for misinterpretation. There are worse slang-type of expressions IMO; *handshaking* might well become increasingly popular in the very near future.

Answer (score 0):

*Handshake* is a noun, but, whilst I'm no grammarian, it sounds okay to me to use it as a verb. This happens extensively with other nouns, so why not with this one?

Comment: There is not a single word in the English language that cannot be verbed.